# how to include XSD schema files in Silverlight library?

Tags: silverlight

Within a Silverlight library, I need to validate incoming XML against a schema.  The schema is composed of 5 interdependent .xsd files;  the main file uses "xs:import" to reference all of the others, and there are other references among them.

Assuming that the .xsd files need to be distributed with the library (i.e. not hosted on some well-known external URL), how should I structure my project to include them?

I have found that I can embed them in the library project with build type "Resource" and then load them (individually) using Application.GetResourceStream() and a relative URI with the ";content" flag in it.  But if I take this approach, can I validate against the interdependent set of 5 files?  What happens when the schema parser tries to resolve the interdependencies?

Or should I embed them with build type "Content" and access the main one with some other sort of URL?

Or???

To summarize:  how should I use these 5 .xsd files in my project so that I will be able to validate XML against them?

EDIT:  It's not clear whether it's even possible to validate in Silverlight.  I spun off [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435244/is-it-possible-to-validate-xml-against-an-xsd-in-silverlight-3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot say much about Silverlight limitations with respect to validation, but the question itself is more generic - one might want to store .xsd files as resources in a desktop .NET application, for example - so I will answer that part.

You can have full control over resolution of URIs in `xs:import` by means of [`XmlSchemaSet.XmlResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.xmlresolver.aspx) property. Just create your own subclass of `XmlResolver`, override `GetEntity()` method, and implement it using `GetResourceStream()`, or `GetManifestResourceStream()`, or whichever other way you prefer.