# Is it possible to validate XML against an XSD in Silverlight 3?

Tags: validation, silverlight-3.0, xsd

Is seems like all the commonly-used classes for XMLValidation, for example XmlValidatingReader, are absent (or present "for interface compatibility only") in Silverlight.

Is there any way to validate XML against an XSD schema in Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but I still don't think this is still possible in SL3:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/53434/138536.aspx

If you *really*, *really* need to reuse a .NET assembly in SL you can do so, but it means packaging that up with your application. I don't recommend this, but details on how to do it can be found here: http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/12/Reusing-NET-Assemblies-in-Silverlight

Hope this helps.